# Bottom navigation: Colour on selected text?

Tags: usability, bottom-navigation

Why is it so common that at bottom navigation many apps choose a highlight colour that is hard to read?

Why don't they use a different colour to highlight and a different colour for the text?
Is it just aesthetics or I'm missing something?

**Examples (of what I consider hard to read):**

[image]

[image]

[image]

**Example of what I think we should be seeing more:**

[image]

[image]

Comment: Personally I prefer the first examples. The coloured text makes it obvious it is selected, where as just a coloured icon then I can't tell if it's selected, or it's just the icon is a different colour for some unknown reason. I think overall it is just design preference, although it's important to ensure the text colour contrasts well with the background.

Answer (score 1):

It is hard to say exactly why, as this could be as simple as the fact that no designers were involved, or the designers had to adhere to certain branding guidelines (for choice of colours), or the designers just ignored best practices.

It would be good to get a screenshot of the rest of the app for more context, but even if you do it doesn't necessarily help you work out exactly why this is the case.